# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы захотели производить компоненты трубопроводной арматуры из российского металла и мы это делаем!

Имеет ли значение восклицательная интонация или повтор подлежащего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сложносочиненном предложении запятая перед союзами и, да (в значении "и"), ***или, либо*** не ставится, если соединяемые ими предложения объединены вопросительной, восклицательной интонацией. 
Ср.: ***Как часто мы собирались  вместе и какие вели интересные беседы!***
См. Справочник -практикум. Орфография, Пунктуация. Розенталь, Д.Э. Стр.246. ***Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М.,2009.***

Comment: Да, спасибо. Просто мне казалось, что здесь первое предложение не восклицательное.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении нужно поставить тире, так как части по значению как бы противопоставлены (захотели - сделали). ***Мы захотели производить компоненты трубопроводной арматуры из российского металла - и мы это делаем!*** В сложносочинённом предложении тире ставится, если части по значению противопоставлены или второе предложение имеет значение неожиданного присоединения.

Comment: Здесь нет никакого противопоставления или неожиданного присоединения. тире возможно, но авторское.